# Line Breaks in Options of Radio Form Element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I need to display a number of addresses in a `Zend_Form`. The nature of the form dictates I'd use `Zend_Form_Element_Radio`. Each address is to be displayed as

```
Surname Name
Street No.
Zip City
```

But I can only acchieve

```
Surname Name Street No. Zip City
```

All the words are in one line.

Now, I read somewhere that I can tell the Label Decorator to render HTML tags like `<br>` like so:

```php
$element->getDecorator('Label')->setOption('escape', false);
```

But this only seems to work for the main label of the element, in this case `Addresses`. So the `<br>`-Tags are still displayed in my output now:

```
Surname Name<br>Street No.<br>Zip City
```

Does anybody know how to also get HTML to render in the individual input tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use custom zend form decorator with your current form

you can use below code and [link](https://github.com/Emagister/zend-form-decorators-bootstrap/issues/39) to add

Also if you want to change any more html changes you can make it as your custom.

Comment: I'm afraid you missunderstood my question: I do not want to remove the line break between radio options but add new line breaks within each label of a radio button.

Comment: sorry to misunderstood your question..now i have updated my answer which will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks very much, although I hat hoped there was a better solution than writing a custom decorator :-(
Your link seems to go to a issue tracker, is there any specific file in that project you wanted to show me or is it more of a generic "look at those classes"?